# ASP.NET MVC 5 Default route not matching no parameters url

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I am using route attributes to route my ASP app.
I managed to setup most of my app, however I am facing a huge problem with the home page.

I want it whenever the user enters the address of the website, to be taken to the home page:

So

```
http://localhost:25902/
```

and

```
http://localhost:25902/Home/Index
```

Should transfer to /Home/Index.

My Route Config looks like this:

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {

        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

And my Home Controller and Index Action are the following :

```
[RoutePrefix("Home")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Route("Index")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

But whenever I acess only loalhost:25902 with nothing to follow it. I get a 404 error.

I really dont understand what the issue is and would love some help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because according to your attribute route it will go to the `index page` when you enter `/Home/Index` so you should add `[Route("~/")]` to get to the default index page when you enter the `loalhost:25902` address like this

```
[RoutePrefix("Home")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Route("~/")]
    [Route("Index")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

and another way is to remove  `[Route("Index")]` and Convention default route will redirect you to `loalhost:25902`

Comment: No, there is some other issue. Coz same url localhost:25902 works for me with same code as in the question.

Comment: @VivekSingh mvc 5 and are you sure         routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes(); is on the top ?

Comment: Ah, there lies the issue. It wasn't on top. Thanks